# Redefining _WIN32_WINNT while using precompiled headers

Tags: c++, windows

Hi I currently have a problem redefining _WIN32_WINNT even though I have

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#define WINVER _WIN32_WINNT
```

in my stdafx.h it still defaults to 0x0603

I'm currently using DDSTextureLoader that came with DirectX Tutorials and by beeing 603 it uses CreateFile2 and not CreateFile which creates an error :(

Comment: You probably put it in the wrong spot.  We can't see where you put it.

Comment: can it  be possible to define winver, as it could work in both windows 7 and 10 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all the `#define`s in the header files, and add the preprocessor definitions `-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600;-DWINVER=_WIN32_WINNT` in the project configuration. This makes sure that the definitions take effect at the very beginning of the compiling process. For the details, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8(v=vs.120).aspx).

If it's not appropriate to remove the `#define`s in the headers. You may change them to the following:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#  define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#endif
#ifndef WINVER
#  define WINVER _WIN32_WINN
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you adding into preprocessor worked right now :)